# query in firebase recyclerview adapter doesnt work

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying trying to populate data in my firebase recyclerview using data from my firebase database.I am using the "query" functionality to filter the results but I am getting a null pointer exception error from the "query"  when i am running the app but the "query" is not returning "null" from debugging. This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.users_list);
    users2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    users2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    users2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

            halls2 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Male").child(user_id).child("halls").getValue();
            halls1 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Female").child(user_id).child("halls").getValue();

            if(dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(user_id)){
            }
            else{
                query = databaseReference.child("Male").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls1);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){


            if(dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(user_id)){

                query = databaseReference.child("Female").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls2);


            }
            else{
                query = databaseReference.child("Male").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls1);

            }



        }

        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder>(
            User.class, R.layout.users_row, UserViewholder.class, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewholder viewHolder, User model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setLevels(model.getLevels());
            viewHolder.setDownloadUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getDownloadUrl());
        }

    };

    users2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

DATABASE STRUCTURE

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "Female" : {
      "WwBjblOo8maSP5PXlYviONrS3Oo2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2Fecf2758a-5628-4297-bcb3-e8c3f138cbbd.jpeg?alt=media&token=1ca6067d-6c08-49b9-a2bf-6a8315ada067",
        "halls" : "Kwapong",
        "levels" : "300",
        "username" : "merylstre"
      },
      "X8c80zaY0kfT5KVoTFHbhPIEG9z2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F51dc26a1-45e8-4897-9c2f-14caf8e79cc5.jpeg?alt=media&token=90818c1e-167e-4799-bc29-b3fe52529cd2",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "hashcodef"
      }
    },
    "Male" : {
      "2EXejmHoMlWoKSDb5APvSt8do5e2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F83ca18a0-63a5-477a-ab1e-b2732b3ebfa1.jpeg?alt=media&token=b8626221-a67c-48e3-b958-d373c9f63c69",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "fillman"
      },
      "BW79oGosAIhdxDxYXbtHbSbC0D23" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F90b93b19-230b-4f28-b394-358d0c516c5c.jpeg?alt=media&token=0c82c272-d6fb-46e8-a6cf-581f5501de7b",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "radjames"
      },
      "Mop4hbS0zne6QS3woum1udLgwqf1" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F78621a8b-7d67-413c-9e57-f378e60ba41e.jpeg?alt=media&token=3982ee0a-2a34-41b3-9250-f0884531ee86",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "radjohn"
      },
      "VvnOY3k7Cwa36bJW55JiZDJRwPN2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F1ac7080f-8db8-49a7-bb76-34b007deb839.jpeg?alt=media&token=6d100527-80d3-49b3-b0ae-617dd55e64de",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "ciryadams"
      },
      "WOT11DVkoVb9owzK4qKHbvT4ODF2" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F3fda02ae-c577-4a4a-86c1-cadcaf518c97.jpeg?alt=media&token=5baf2a79-b14c-4e28-b7bb-77e55ae08e55",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "markzuck"
      },
      "dbnmFoC4hnSCsXsxJgVO0Q7GYx13" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F2366c787-fb16-4049-9c7d-3d0c2a09ab9b.jpeg?alt=media&token=25bda8dd-ab24-4b9b-8299-534e49bf9ed4",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "dasdsada"
      },
      "iqZfSgGNpPZ4HDtOUuHYZ1u8x273" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2Fc52cd467-05b9-4ece-8085-4cdf502839c5.jpeg?alt=media&token=4c9eb36e-4644-49ec-85eb-c2fef38ca50e",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "maameEsi"
      },
      "jj9yycmDNbZwiPVTLrRyYZheM702" : {
        "downloadUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/loginapp-8088d.appspot.com/o/userProfiles%2F5c4a34b2-bc7b-43e7-8b00-7e0bf63ff252.jpeg?alt=media&token=59a11905-a67d-48ea-9f16-10ffd3915876",
        "halls" : "Sarbah",
        "levels" : "100",
        "username" : "hashcode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ERROR LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: dev.mintz.loginapp, PID: 3157
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dev.mintz.loginapp/dev.mintz.loginapp.Users}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.<init>(FirebaseArray.java:41)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.<init>(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:91)
                      at dev.mintz.loginapp.Users$2.<init>(Users.java:0)
                      at dev.mintz.loginapp.Users.onCreate(Users.java:108)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: The query is null when you create the adapter. It's not assigned until Firebase returns data.

Comment: ohk! Please is there a way i can query before firebase returns data ? @cricket_007

Comment: You just need to initialize `query` to literally anything other than null.

Comment: But just because you reassigned `query` within the results, your adapter will not change

Comment: So from my code, the adapter is bn created before  the query results are returned? @cricket_007

Comment: Precisely. Your `new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` method might as well be immediately after `users2.setLayoutManager`. Just because `query =` is **between** those lines of code, does not at all indicate when it runs.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this please? @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` method might as well be immediately after `users2.setLayoutManager`.

Just because you have code of `query =` between some lines of code, does not at all indicate that is when it runs - especially since Firebase is async.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users_list);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    users2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    users2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    users2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // query = ... ; // Set this to literally anything but 'null'

    // Otherwise, your error is here...
    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder>(
            User.class, R.layout.users_row, UserViewholder.class, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewholder viewHolder, User model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setLevels(model.getLevels());
            viewHolder.setDownloadUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getDownloadUrl());
        }

    };

    users2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    // The rest of your code
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        ...
```

**Then**, in the remainder of your code, you can update `query`, but you must notify the adapter that the query changed.

```
public void onDataChange(...) {
    ...

    query = ... ; // Update query
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Update UI
}
```